# How to get value of checked gridview column

Tags: javascript, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hi guys i have a gridview like below
and i want to get the 'user_id' of the checked column
how can i do that???

I could easily get the checked column id but i dont know how to get data of those checked column in gridview
i want to get it via javascript so that i can pass it to service

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'showOnEmpty'=>true,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
            [

                'attribute' => 'event_id',
                'label' => 'Event Title',
                'value' => 'event.title'
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'user_id',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'value' => 'users.email',
            ],
            'user_type',
        ],
    ]);
 ?>
```

and here is my javascript to get ids of checked column

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
btnCheck  = $("#send");
btnCheck.click(function() {
    var keys = $("#w0").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
  }
});
```

Let me tell you the flow of this

On homepage is a gridview like this
[image]
Now user will click on that small user sign and that will open the page you can see below

Thats when i want to send messages to all selected users

[image]
Because in my case `title` is from different table and `name` and `email` are from different table so i want `ids` of `user` table

For that i want `user_id` but i am getting some random values 
What can i do here???

I tried this but its returning some random string

```
public function search($params)
{

    if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id='';
    }
    else{
        $id=$_GET['id'];
    }

    $query = Checkin::find()->where(['event_id'=> $id]);

    $query->joinWith(['event', 'users']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_date' => $this->created_date,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'updated_date' => $this->updated_date,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.email', $this->user_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_type', $this->user_type]);

    $dataProvider->keys ='user_id';

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: you want data of gridview row or column?

Comment: @kailas i want column.. like i want `user_id` of checked column.. `ùser_id` is in 3d column..

Comment: check in these link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53777-gridview-get-selected-colum/ hop it solve your problem

Comment: @Kailas i have seen that but my scenario is a littlebit different because in my case i dont want the `pks` of the grid i want data in 3rd column. I am displaying data from 2 different tables.

Comment: you got any error msg. in console?

Comment: @gamitg no i got the rowids of the checked column but i dont want that i want `user_id` which is in 3rd column... i have included a image in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your DataProvider set `$dataProvider->keys ='userId'` then you will able to get all keys of `user_id`

`data-id` of GridView and get allSelectedColumns

Comment: should i do that in the gridview? or in the controller?

Comment: `$dataProvider` may be your searchModel when created through Crud

Comment: so should i do that in mysearch model or in controller? i tried doing in controller but didnt work...

Comment: i have added the searchmodel and the code you told me to use but its not working

Comment: i got it.. `$dataProvider->keys` takes array as values but i wanted to set the column as data key so i needed `$dataProvider->key` instead and it solved the problem. Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to just replace this code

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
```

with below code

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'checkboxOptions' => function($data) {
        return ['value' => $data->user_id];
    },
],
```

Comment: no it didnt change anything.. its still returning something else.. I dont even know what its returning value